# Error with try and except and thread

Tags: python, multithreading, try-catch

I've written a program using thread. Here's an example of the code I've written:

```
from time import sleep, time
from threading import Thread

def UserInfo():
    global gamesummary
    Thread(target = CheckTime).start()
    gamesummary=open("gamesummary.txt","w+")
    AskQuestions()

def CheckTime():
    global gamesummary
    sleep(5)
    print("Time's up!")
    gamesummary.close()
    raise ValueError

def AskQuestions():
    global gamesummary
    try:
        while True:
            input("Program asks questions correctly here: ")
            gamesummary.write("Program correctly records information here")
    except ValueError:
        EndProgram()

def EndProgram():
    end=input("Would you like to play again?: ")

    if(end.lower()=="yes"):
        UserInfo()
    elif(end.lower()=="no"):
        print("Thank you for playing.")
        sleep(1)
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        print("Please enter either 'yes' or 'no'.\n")
        EndProgram()
```

Everything in the program is done correctly and continues normally but this error shows up before EndProgram():

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\akeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "x-wingide-python-shell://105807224/2", line 15, in CheckTime
ValueError
```

This error doesn't stop the program from functioning.

I don't understand why the try and except statement isn't catching this exception. I think it is because I'm creating two errors? I'm new to using python, and I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting a `ValueError` in the background thread is that you're explicitly raising a `ValueError` in the target function for that thread:

```
def CheckTime():
    global gamesummary
    sleep(5)
    print("Time's up!")
    gamesummary.close()
    raise ValueError
```

When a background thread raises an exception, instead of killing the whole program, it just dumps the traceback to stderr and kills the thread, leaving the other threads running. Which is what you're seeing here.

If you don't want that, just leave that line off.

If you were hoping the exception would somehow affect the main thread, it's not going to do that. But you don't *need* it to do that. You're closing the file out from under the main thread, which means `AskQuestions` is going to get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` exception when it tries to `write` to the file. Which you're properly handling. This is a bit of an odd design, but it will work as intended; you don't need to add anything extra on top of it.

If you were hoping to catch the exception from the main thread, that won't work either—but again, it isn't needed. The main thread isn't affected by the background thread's exception.